# Function to count and display the number of all subcategories in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I tried to find a function for Wordpress that allows me to count the number of all the subcategories that exist to show it, so far without success.

Some help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only number then you could try this

```
$args = ['fields' => 'id=>parent', 'get' => 'all'];
$categories = get_categories($args);
$subcategories = array_filter($categories);
echo "Total subcategories: " . count($subcategories);
```

Comment: I just tried it and it works correctly, just what I wanted, that I would only count the subcategories. Thanks